# How to pass custom message along with mib using pysnmp

Tags: pysnmp

I using pysnmp "4.4.12". I have a very specific requirement where I need to send snmptrap with custom message. I am able to send trap using my code but not sure how to pass custom message.

```
next(sendNotification(SnmpEngine(),
     CommunityData(community),
     UdpTransportTarget((target_ip, port)),
     ContextData(),
     'trap',
     NotificationType(ObjectIdentity('ILO-INLET-TEMP-MIB', 'inletTempHighWarning'))))
```

If I am using "ObjectType" function in place of "NotificationType" like below:
[ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('ILO-INLET-TEMP-MIB', 'inletTempHighWarning'), OctetString(msg))]))

I am able to pass custom message but I need it with "NotificationType"  function only as my receiver tool is not able to match with mib data if passing with "ObjectType" function.

Please help whoever have any clue.

Comment: SNMP is very strict protocol and TRAP only passes information defined in the TRAP-TYPE objects in related MIB documents. So, no, no one can help you pass a custom message, unless that `inletTempHighWarning` TRAP-TYPE has defined something for you.